# How can I achieve two different Next.js components to be displayed inline?

Tags: css, next.js, components, tailwind-css, sidebar

> The problem

[image]

> I want to achieve like this.

[image]

> Here is the code of the layout which I imported my side bar and 2nd component which is child.

```
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";


   const Layout = ({ children }) => {
   return (
   <div className="h-screen flex flex-row justify-start">
   <Sidebar />
   <div className="bg-primary flex-1 p-4">
      {children}
    </div>
    </div>
   )
   }

   export default Layout
```

> Here is for the side bar

```
 return (
<div className= "h-screen px-2 pt-8 pb-4 flex justify-between bg-gray-100 flex-col border">
  <div className="flex items-center justify-center relative">
    <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
    <div style={{ minWidth: "2.5rem" }}>
        <Image
          src={userProfile}
          alt="user profile"
          width={60}
          height={0}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Honestly I was able to achieve and solve my problem when I removed the "fixed" property (which I want the sidebar follows whenever I'm scrolling). However, the problem occurs when I put it back. I tried another option using "sticky top-0" just to solve the issue, but it didn't work.

This is where i put the "fixed" property.

```
<div className= "h-screen px-2 pt-8 pb-4 flex justify-between bg-gray-100 flex-col border">
```